# Failed or success query always return true

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

**code:**

```
$new_deb = 5;
//prepare query();
$q = 'START TRANSACTION;';
for($l = 0; $l < $cond; $l++){
    if($uploaded == 0 || $uploaded == "0"){
        $q .= ' INSERT INTO vocher (`vo_type_id`, `account_id`, `value`, `desc`, `user_id`, `status_id`, `date`, `debtor_id`)';
        $q .= ' VALUES ("'.$vouchertype.'", "'.$voucheracc[$l].'","'.$vdebvalue[$l].'", "'.$vdebdesc[$l].'","'.$_POST['usrSes'].'", "'.$status.'","'.$vocherdate[$l].'", "'.$new_deb.'");';
    }else{
        $q .= ' INSERT INTO vocher (`vo_type_id`, `account_id`, `value`, `desc`, `user_id`, `status_id`, `date`, `debtor_id`, `link`)';
        $q .= ' VALUES ("'.$vouchertype.'", "'.$voucheracc[$l].'","'.$vdebvalue[$l].'", "'.$vdebdesc[$l].'","'.$_POST['usrSes'].'", "'.$status.'","'.$vocherdate[$l].'", "'.$new_deb.'", "'.$newAttach.'");';
    }

    $q .= ' SET @lastId = (SELECT `id` FROM vocher ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);';
    if($voCc[$l] != 'e'){
        for($h = 0; $h < count($voCc[$l]); $h++){
            if($voCc[$l][$h] != 'e'){
                $q .= ' INSERT INTO voucher_cc (`voucher`, `cc`) VALUES (@lastId, "'.$voCc[$l][$h].'");';
            }
        }
    }

    if(in_array($voucheracc[$l], $inResetAccs)){
        $q .= ' INSERT INTO resets ( `type`, `acc`, `user`, `value`, `desc`, `debtor_id`, `date`, `status`)';
        $q .= ' VALUES ("IN", "'.$voucheracc[$l].'", "'.$_POST['usrSes'].'", "'.$vdebvalue[$l].'", "'.$vdebdesc[$l].'", "'.$new_deb.'", "'.$vocherdate[$l].'", "1");';
    }
}

for($z = 0; $z < $chqradiolength; $z++){
    if ($chqradio[$z] == "0") {
        $q .= ' INSERT INTO creditor (`acc_id`, `value`, `bank_id`, `debtor_id`, `cheque_no`, `issue_date`, `available_date`, `vo_type_id`, `desc`, `date`, `user`)';
        $q .= ' VALUES ("'.$chequeAcc[$z].'", "'.$vvalue[$z].'", "'.$banks[$z].'", "'.$new_deb.'", "'.$vsn[$z].'", "'.$issuesdates[$z].'", "'.$availabledate[$z].'", "'.$vouchertype.'", "'.$vdesc[$z].'", "'.$credates[$z].'", "'.$_POST['usrSes'].'");';
        $q .= ' SET @creLastId = (SELECT `id` FROM creditor ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);';
        for($x = 0; $x < count($chequeCc[$z]); $x++){
            $q .= ' INSERT INTO creditor_cc (`creditor`, `cc`) VALUES (@creLastId, "'.$chequeCc[$z][$x].'");';
        }
    }else{
        $q .= ' INSERT INTO creditor (`acc_id`, `value`, `debtor_id`, `date`, `desc`, `vo_type_id`, `user`)';
        $q .= ' VALUES ("'.$creaccs[$z].'", "'.$vvalue[$z].'", "'.$new_deb.'" , "'.$credates[$z].'" , "'.$vdesc[$z].'" , "'.$vouchertype.'", "'.$_POST['usrSes'].'");';
        $q .= ' SET @creLastId = (SELECT `id` FROM creditor ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);';

        if($creCc[$z] != 'e'){
            for($x = 0; $x < count($creCc[$z]); $x++){
                if($creCc[$z][$x] != 'e'){
                    $q .= ' INSERT INTO creditor_cc (`creditor`, `cc`) VALUES (@creLastId, "'.$creCc[$z][$x].'");';
                }
            }
        }

        if(in_array($creaccs[$z], $outResetAccs)){
            $q .= ' INSERT INTO resets (`type`, `acc`, `user`, `value`, `desc`, `debtor_id`, `date`, `status`)';
            $q .= ' VALUES ("OUT", "'.$creaccs[$z].'" , "'.$_POST['usrSes'].'" , "'.$vvalue[$z].'", "'.$vdesc[$z].'" , "'.$new_deb.'", "'.$credates[$z].'", "1");';
        }
    }
}
$q .= ' COMMIT;';
$vocher_obj->query($q);
$check = $vocher_obj->execute();
if($check){
    $res = 1;
}else{
    $res = 23;
}

echo $res;
```

This code is to generate some queries.

Those queries always return "true" even if I change the table name to a "non existing" table in the database, while it should return "false"!

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: you shouldn't be stuffing multiple query statements into a single query call. and your code is inherently racy. you shouldn't be using `select ...` to get the last generated id. there's `insert_id()`. There is NO guarantee that someone else won't insert a record behind your back.

Comment: That's why I'm creating a transaction, so no one else can insert before the transaction is done. And I'm using PDO not MYSQLI

Comment: make sure your transaction settings are actually working in repeated read mode, then...

Comment: You are using PDO but your SQL is wide open to injection...

Comment: @MarcB, how could I make sure of that?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, you mean by not using "bind"?

Comment: Output the query before executing it. Maybe you are just running `START TRANSACTION; COMMIT;` all the time?

Comment: No, I made a var_dump on "$q" and it is right - @dognose

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is caused by this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61613

It says, if the FIRST statement is valid, pdo will not return an error. And `START TRANSACTION;` is always valid.

The bug is reported to be *unfixed* upto verison 5.6.7 of PHP.

Not sure if this bug affects the return statement as well, as it is about missing exception throwing. But should be easy to test: Add a invalid statement before anything else and see if the return value is false.

Also for transactions with pdo you should look at

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$pdo->commit();
$pdo->rollback();
```

To avoid the bug mentioned above, stuff your queries into an array, and run them like this (simplified):

```
function runQueries($pdo, $queries){
  try{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    foreach($queries as $q){
       $pdo->exec($q);
    }
    $pdo->commit();
    return true;
  }catch (PDOException $e){
    $pdo->rollback();
    return false;
  }
}
```

ofc. you need to configure PDO to throw execptions, using

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=someDB', 'username', 'password', array(
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```

Comment: I think I have to run the query function first before "$q->execute();" right?

Comment: @MohamedSalah the example uses `exec()` on the PDOObject not `execute()` on the PDOStatement. Adapt to your needs.

Comment: can you show me how to declare "$queries" array please?